# how can I use the ctl+arrow windows shortcut to navigate through each word in a text at Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing

How can I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> windows shortcut to navigate through a text sting on a Mac?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how to change the default ⌥-arrow shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use ⌥-arrow (ALT-arrow)?

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` in `~/Library/Keybindings` and add the following text:

```
{
    "^\UF702" = (moveWordLeft:);
    "^\UF703" = (moveWordRight:);
}
```

This will reassign `Ctrl-Left` and `Ctrl-Right` from their default `moveToBeginningOfLine/moveToEndOfLine` to movement by words, the same action as performed by `Opt-Left/Right`.

Answer (score 1):

[List of Windows/Mac OS X keyboard shortcut equivalents on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts)